# Why don't I get traces when sending OpenTelemetry to Jaeger?

Tags: rust, open-telemetry, jaeger, rust-tracing

I'm learning [tracing](https://docs.rs/tracing/0.1.25/tracing/) and [open-telemetry](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust) in Rust. I feel there are too many concepts and too many crates (at least in Rust) to see traces.

I wrote a simple lib app that adds two `u32`s:

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub fn add(f: u32, s: u32) -> u32 {
    let span = tracing::info_span!("Add function", ?f, ?s);
    let _guard = span.enter();
    tracing::info!("Info event");
    f.add(s)
}
```

And then I'm using the lib in my binary app:

```
use TracedLibrary::add;
use tracing_opentelemetry::OpenTelemetryLayer;
use tracing_subscriber::util::SubscriberInitExt;
use opentelemetry::{global, sdk::propagation::TraceContextPropagator};
use tracing_subscriber::layer::SubscriberExt;
use tracing_subscriber::Registry;

fn main() {
    setup_global_subscriber();
    let sum = add::add(1, 2);
}

fn setup_global_subscriber() {
    global::set_text_map_propagator(TraceContextPropagator::new());
    let (tracer, _uninstall) = opentelemetry_jaeger::new_pipeline()
        .with_service_name("trace_demo_2")
        .install().expect("Error initializing Jaeger exporter");
    let telemetry = tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(tracer);

    Registry::default()
        .with(telemetry).init();
}
```

The most confusing part is my apps `Cargo.toml` which looks like

```toml
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.2.15" }
tracing-opentelemetry = { version= "0.11.0"}
opentelemetry = "0.12.0"
opentelemetry-jaeger = {version = "0.11.0" }
```

What on earth are those different crates are for? The only crate that makes sense is `opentelemetry-jaeger`. Are others even required?

And to my main question: I'm running Jaeger's all-in-one docker container. But when I visit `http://localhost:16686`, I see no traces.
Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: The [tracing ecosystem](https://crates.io/crates/tracing#ecosystem) is very modular where integrations with tools and frameworks are separate crates. OpenTelemetry is [also modular](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust#ecosystem) allowing exporting to various formats/apis via different crates. So here you go from tracing -> tracing-subscriber -> tracing-opentelemetry -> opentelemetry -> opentelementry-jaeger in order to get tracing to output to jaeger. It may be less crates to just use the opentelemetry tools directly, however I find tracing to be very convenient.

Comment: Your chain is correct. I also think I dont need `opentelemetry` explicitly. The only reason Im adding it as a dep is for this single line `global::set_text_map_propagator(TraceContextPropagator::new());`. I dont know what that line does btw. But anyways, I still dont get any traces or spans. :(

Answer (score 2):

Turns out when I create the Jaeger pipeline in `setup_global_subscriber()`,  the `_uninstall` being returned gets dropped at the end of the function.
And when it gets dropped, collector shuts down.

To get traces I had to move contents of `setup_global_subscriber()` in `main()`.

Comment: Maybe you could have your `setup_global_subscriber` function return `_uninstall`, and keep the returned `_uninstall` in the scope of `main`?

Comment: You may find solace that the API has changed since then and you don't have to worry about managing an `uninstall` variable anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.

```rust
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber);
```

This sets a global `Dispatcher`, which `Dispatcher.inner` is your `subscriber`.